# NodeJs request modules runtime Error: ./..../tough-cookie/package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, request, package.json, npm-request

When I install NodeJs module, there is a bug in the running.

`request` module is the latest version:

```
npm install request    

stream.js:74
          throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
          ^
    Error: ./~/request/~/tough-cookie/package.json
    Module parse failed: /Users/DongYao/Develop/proj-1/weicang_c/node_modules/request/node_modules/tough-cookie/package.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | {
    |   "author": {
    |     "name": "Jeremy Stashewsky",
    |     "email": "jstashewsky@salesforce.com"
     @ ./~/request/~/tough-cookie/lib/cookie.js 38:14-40./~/request/~/mime-types/~/mime-db/db.json
    Module parse failed: /Users/DongYao/Develop/proj-1/weicang_c/node_modules/request/node_modules/mime-types/node_modules/mime-db/db.json Line 2: Unexpected token :
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | {
    |   "application/1d-interleaved-parityfec": {
    |     "source": "iana"
    |   },
     ==================
     and more.........
```

Please help me.

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce this error. What version of `npm` do you have installed?

Comment: What request version are you trying to install? Check your package.json

Comment: npm version is v2.14.12, request version is v2.69.0